# .htaccess subdomain redirect problem

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have a website let's say `www.example.com` and I have a subdomain `something.example.com`

Both main domain and sub domain are pointing to directory "public_html"

I have .htaccess on root which redirects any URL without www to www.
For e.g. if user enters example.com then he will be redirected to www.example.com
If user enters `example.com/mypage.html` then he will be redirected to `www.example.com/mypage.html`

Now the problem is this is also affecting my subdomain. Because if someone enters `something.example.com/visit.html` then he is redirect to `www.example.com/visit.html`

I don't want this! If user enters subdomain then I don't want to redirected to www domain. This is what I have in my .htacces file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.stackoverflow.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.stackoverflow.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Can you please tell me what should I do to solve above problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have access to your webserver configuration? This is better done by configuring the webserver.

On apache you would configure one virtual domain like this:

`<VirtualHost *:80>`

```
        ServerName somedomainiwanttoredirect.com
        ServerAlias maybe.somemoredomainstoredirect.com
        ServerAlias orsubdomains.toredirect.com
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.target.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

`</VirtualHost>`

and on your real configuration, the www.target.com you add your subdomains that you do not want to be redirected:

`ServerAlias subdomain.target.com`

Comment: I have already done this as follows:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(.*).stackoverflow.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.stackoverflow.com/$1 [R=301,L]